# How to fix this formatting issue?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am attempting to template a system properties file using Jinja2. I'm using a list, a for loop and an if loop to cycle through various hostnames and to produce them in a list as a variables property. However, when I then deploy this code using ansible, the formatting comes out wrong and the next line is attached to the first line with no line break.

I have tried numerous different ways of layout, but none of them seem to work.

```
database.url = {%- set list1 = application_host.split(',') -%} {%- for list in list1 -%} {{ list }}:{{ db_port }}{%- if not loop.last -%},{%- endif -%}{%- endfor -%}

database.name = {{application_db_name }}
```

This is how it actually looks in the file:

```
database.url =db-cluster-router-1:4526,db-cluster-router-2:4526solr.database.name = DATABASENAME
```

I am expecting a line break between the two variables. E.g.:

```
database.url = db-cluster-router-1:4526,db-cluster-router-2:4526 
database.name = DATABASENAME
```

Comment: Try to replace the last `-%}` with the `+%}` This change should keep the trailing spaces and new lines.

Comment: @SergeiSadovnikov Afraid that didn't help, just failed to build on the ansible run.